# ReactJs - test multiple calls in redux-saga with expectSaga

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

I'm using expectSaga ('[redux-saga-test-plan](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan)') to test one of my sagas and I'm wondering how to test multiple calls made within the same saga.

**Sagas.js**

```
export function* fetchSomething(arg){
  const response = yield call(executeFetch, arg);
  if(response.status === 200){
    // trigger success action
  } else if (response.status >= 400){
    const errResp = yield response.json();
    const errorCode = yield call(sharedUtilToExtractErrors, errResp);
    yield put(
      { type: 'FETCH_FAILED', errorMessage: UI_ERR_MSG, errorCode }
    );
  }
}
```

**Unit test**

```
import { expectSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan';

describe('fetchSomething', () => {

   // positive paths

   // ..

   // negative paths

   it('fetches something and with status code 400 triggers FETCH_FAILED with error message and extracted error code', () => {
     const serverError = { message: 'BANG BANG BABY!' };
     const koResponse = new Response(
       JSON.stringify(serverError),
       { status: 400, headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' } }
     );

     return expectSaga(fetchSomething)
        .provide(
          {
            call: () => koResponse,
            call: () => serverError.message,
          }
        )
        .put({
           type: 'FETCH_FAILED', errorMessage: UI_ERR_MSG, serverError.message
        })
        .run();
    })
})
```

Clearly having the "call" attribute twice in the same object passed in to *provide()* doesn't work but also calling *provide()* twice doesn't do the trick. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can *provide* multiple *calls* according to the [documentation](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan#mocking-with-providers):

```
.provide([ // this external array is actually optional
  [call(executeFetch, arg), koResponse],
  [call(sharedUtilToExtractErrors, serverError), serverError.message],
])
```

or if you're lazy and don't want to specify the arguments:

```
import * as matchers from 'redux-saga-test-plan/matchers';

.provide(
 [matchers.call.fn(executeFetch), koResponse],
 [matchers.call.fn(sharedUtilToExtractErrrors), serverError.message],
)
```

Neither of these two worked for me though as for some reason it was not mocking out the dependencies and still calling them caused errors.

I solved using a **dynamic provider**:

```
.provide({
  // select(effect, next) { return 'something-for-a-selector' },
  call(effect) {
    switch(effect.fn.constructor.name) {
      case executeFetch.constructor.name: return koResponse;
      case sharedUtilToExtractErrors.constructor.name: return serverError.message;
      default: throw new Error('Unknown function called in test');
    }
  }
})
```